# RPi3 unable to connect to wifi

Tags: pi-3, wifi

We have an RPi3, but we are not able to connect to the wifi network. It shows "No wireless interfaces found". We have tried modifying 'wpa_supplicant.conf' file but it didnt help. Also we  tried ipconfig, it doesn't show the RPi's ip address. Any suggestions?

Comment: 2.4 or 5 GHz wifi? RPi 3 model B+?

Comment: Try connecting a USB dongle and/or Ethernet cable. Do you still get the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what command produces the message but there are a number of things to check:

`lsusb -t` will give you a tree of usb-devices. The standard `wlan0` sould be a device with `Driver=r8712u`. If there is no such device, you may try `modprobe r8712u`. If that doesn't work, your wifi on the pi may be broken.

```
grep dhcpcd /var/log/daemon.log
```

This should give a number of messages, for example:

```
wlan0: carrier acquired
wlan0: IAID f6:de:30:ad
wlan0: adding address fe80::20c:f6ff:fede:30ff
```

etetera.

`iwlist wlan0 scan` should give you a number of access points that the pi sees. Check if the pi can see your access-point.

`iwconfig wlan0` will show whether the pi is connected to an access-point.
if it is not: check the `wpa_supplicant.conf`; it may have an error.

`ifconfig wlan0` will show whether you have an IP address on the wlan0 interface, but you already tried that. But if all the rest works, you should put a fixed IP address on the pi in `/etc/dhcpcd.conf`:

```
interface wlan0
static ip_address=192.168.178.4/24
static routers=192.168.178.1
static domain_name_servers=192.168.178.6
```

(adjust to your network). This will work if dhcp on your wifi is broken.

oh, some commands require root-access; you may need to `sudo` them.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solved it ( for rasbian stretch ) after reading hundreds of posts:

https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/wireless-cli.md

Typed:
sudo raspi-config
Typed in ssid and password

Solved

Cheers,
Brad

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the wifi_suppicant service is down. This happened to me 15 days ago while I was updating software. After flashing the latest buster release the problem was gone. So flash the sdcard and you will find it corrected. Backup anything important before doing so.